# Is it possible to change Hazelcast quorum configuration dynamically?

Tags: hazelcast

Let's say, I have a Hazelcast cluster of size 7 and I have defined a quorum as 4 (i.e. n/2+1 ). Now, I am gracefully removing 2 nodes from the cluster, so now, the cluster size is 5. In such case, I want to change quorum size to 3. Is it possible to change quorum size dynamically ?

I want to change quorum configuration only in case of gracefull node removal not in case of node failure or network partition where node is still part of the cluster.

Comment: No this is not possible. Quorum configuration is fixed and does not support dynamic "scaling". Might be an interesting use case though, feel free to create a feature request on github,

Comment: @noctarius, is it possible to decide quorum dynamically by using  quorumConf.setQuorumFunctionImplementation ?

Comment: Hi @AmarGajbhiye, currently, quorum cannot be changed dynamically while the cluster is running. You can only configure it initially and the initial configuration will be used afterwards.